# Publish a Bot created in Bot framework Composer using Azure CLI

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I created a bot in Bot framework Composer, it works fine locally and using Bot Framework emulator, and when I publish it using the Composer publish features it works fine. But I need to publish the bot using Azure CLI, I tried following the steps in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Ccsharp#create-resource-groups

I created an app registration, a web app and a bot. but when I try to access the bot using the "web chat" feature in the Azure portal I get error "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound".

These are the commands I used to create the resources and publish the bot:

Create App registration and secret:

```
 az ad app create --display-name "test" --sign-in-audience "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" 

 az ad app credential reset --id "<app_id>"
```

Create Web app:

```
 az deployment group create --resource-group "test" --template-file "C:\..\template-BotApp-with-rg.json" --parameters "@C:\..\parameters-for-template-BotApp-with-rg.json"
```

Create Azure Bot:

```
 az deployment group create --resource-group "test" --template-file "C:\..\template-AzureBot-with-rg.json" --parameters "@C:\..\parameters-for-template-AzureBot-with-rg.json"
```

Prepare deployment and publish to Azure bot:

```
 az bot prepare-deploy --lang Csharp --code-dir "C:\" --proj-file-path "C:\..\test.csproj"

 az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group "test" --name "test" --src "C:\..\test.zip"
```

I got the templates files from here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/main/generators/dotnet-templates/Microsoft.BotFramework.CSharp.EchoBot/content/DeploymentTemplates/DeployUseExistResourceGroup

I updated the appsettings.json with AppID and password, and I copied the .sln file to the root folder then zipped the root folder:

Comment: If you go to the App Service, then `App Service Editor`; can you please check the `Output` and `Console` windows to see if a more robust error shows up when you reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

- According to my research there are different way to deploy

[image]

- As the above picture mansions User-assigned manage will Support **Azure bot service C# JavaScript SDKs**
- The `single-tenant` will support **Azure Bot and C# and JavaScript SDKs**
- The `Multi-tenant` Support **Azure Bot Service, all frameworks SDK language, composer the Emulator and Ngok**.

-Make sure you are using setting which are used for specific deployment in the document.

- Deploying the app service please follow this [Use Azure CLI to create an App Service resource - Bot Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-app-service?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Cexistingplan).

[image]

- Deploying the bot service follow this [Use Azure CLI to create an Azure Bot resource - Bot Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-azure-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned).

[image]

- [Update project configuration settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Ccsharp#update-project-configuration-settings)

[image]

- [Prepare your project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Ccsharp#update-project-configuration-settings).

[image]

- [Publish your bot to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Ccsharp#publish-your-bot-to-azure)

Comment: These are the exact steps I followed but when I publish the bot, it doesnt work. I get this error, even though the bot works fine locally: There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound –

Comment: follow this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#test-your-bot) it might help.